# pg gem not possible to be installed with bundle install or at all

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, rubygems, pg

i'm trying to install pg gem. I'm a total beginner to ruby on rails and to programming at all. I'm trying to figure that error out since yesterday and already looked at many places for a solution. hope you can help me. thanks
using mac mountain lion
ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [x86_64-darwin12.3.0]
and used to use rails 4.0
Marcs-MacBook-Pro:smartforce marcboehle$ rails -v
Could not find pg-0.16.0 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.

I already tried:

```
Marcs-MacBook-Pro:smartforce marcboehle$ bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/..........
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
Enter your password to install the bundled RubyGems to your system: 
Using rake (10.1.0) 
Using i18n (0.6.5) 
Using minitest (4.7.5) 
Using multi_json (1.7.9) 
Using atomic (1.1.13) 
Using thread_safe (0.1.2) 
Using tzinfo (0.3.37) 
Using activesupport (4.0.0) 
Using builder (3.1.4) 
Using erubis (2.7.0) 
Using rack (1.5.2) 
Using rack-test (0.6.2) 
Using actionpack (4.0.0) 
Using mime-types (1.24) 
Using polyglot (0.3.3) 
Using treetop (1.4.15) 
Using mail (2.5.4) 
Using actionmailer (4.0.0) 
Using activemodel (4.0.0) 
Using activerecord-deprecated_finders (1.0.3) 
Using arel (4.0.0) 
Using activerecord (4.0.0) 
Using bundler (1.3.5) 
Installing coffee-script-source (1.6.3) 
Installing execjs (2.0.0) 
Installing coffee-script (2.2.0) 
Using thor (0.18.1) 
Using railties (4.0.0) 
Installing coffee-rails (4.0.0) 
Using hike (1.2.3) 
Installing jbuilder (1.5.0) 
Installing jquery-rails (3.0.4) 
Installing json (1.8.0) 
Installing pg (0.16.0) 
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
checking for pg_config... yes
Using config values from /usr/bin/pg_config
checking for libpq-fe.h... yes
checking for libpq/libpq-fs.h... yes
checking for pg_config_manual.h... yes
checking for PQconnectdb() in -lpq... yes
checking for PQconnectionUsedPassword()... yes
checking for PQisthreadsafe()... yes
checking for PQprepare()... yes
checking for PQexecParams()... yes
checking for PQescapeString()... yes
checking for PQescapeStringConn()... yes
checking for PQescapeLiteral()... yes
checking for PQescapeIdentifier()... yes
checking for PQgetCancel()... yes
checking for lo_create()... yes
checking for pg_encoding_to_char()... yes
checking for pg_char_to_encoding()... yes
checking for PQsetClientEncoding()... yes
checking for PQlibVersion()... yes
checking for PQping()... yes
checking for PQsetSingleRowMode()... no
checking for rb_encdb_alias()... yes
checking for rb_enc_alias()... yes
checking for rb_thread_call_without_gvl()... yes
checking for rb_thread_call_with_gvl()... yes
checking for rb_thread_fd_select()... yes
checking for rb_w32_wrap_io_handle()... no
checking for PGRES_COPY_BOTH in libpq-fe.h... no
checking for PGRES_SINGLE_TUPLE in libpq-fe.h... no
checking for PG_DIAG_TABLE_NAME in libpq-fe.h... no
checking for struct pgNotify.extra in libpq-fe.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for ruby/st.h... yes
creating extconf.h
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR="
compiling gvl_wrappers.c
compiling pg.c
pg.c:272:9: warning: implicit declaration of function 'PQlibVersion' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
        return INT2NUM(PQlibVersion());
               ^
In file included from pg.c:48:
In file included from ./pg.h:17:
In file included from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby.h:33:
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/ruby.h:1167:21: note: instantiated from:
# define INT2NUM(v) INT2FIX((int)(v))
                    ^
pg.c:272:9: note: instantiated from:
        return INT2NUM(PQlibVersion());
               ^
pg.c:272:17: note: instantiated from:
        return INT2NUM(PQlibVersion());
                       ^
pg.c:375:48: error: use of undeclared identifier 'PQPING_OK'
        rb_define_const(rb_mPGconstants, "PQPING_OK", INT2FIX(PQPING_OK));
                                                      ^
pg.c:375:56: note: instantiated from:
        rb_define_const(rb_mPGconstants, "PQPING_OK", INT2FIX(PQPING_OK));
                                                              ^
pg.c:377:52: error: use of undeclared identifier 'PQPING_REJECT'
        rb_define_const(rb_mPGconstants, "PQPING_REJECT", INT2FIX(PQPING_REJECT));
                                                          ^
pg.c:377:60: note: instantiated from:
        rb_define_const(rb_mPGconstants, "PQPING_REJECT", INT2FIX(PQPING_REJECT));
                                                                  ^
pg.c:379:57: error: use of undeclared identifier 'PQPING_NO_RESPONSE'
        rb_define_const(rb_mPGconstants, "PQPING_NO_RESPONSE", INT2FIX(PQPING_NO_RESPONSE));
                                                               ^
pg.c:379:65: note: instantiated from:
        rb_define_const(rb_mPGconstants, "PQPING_NO_RESPONSE", INT2FIX(PQPING_NO_RESPONSE));
                                                                       ^
pg.c:381:56: error: use of undeclared identifier 'PQPING_NO_ATTEMPT'
        rb_define_const(rb_mPGconstants, "PQPING_NO_ATTEMPT", INT2FIX(PQPING_NO_ATTEMPT));
                                                              ^
pg.c:381:64: note: instantiated from:
        rb_define_const(rb_mPGconstants, "PQPING_NO_ATTEMPT", INT2FIX(PQPING_NO_ATTEMPT));
                                                                      ^
1 warning and 4 errors generated.
make: *** [pg.o] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/marcboehle/.bundler/tmp/25873/gems/pg-0.16.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/marcboehle/.bundler/tmp/25873/gems/pg-0.16.0/ext/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing pg (0.16.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install pg -v '0.16.0'` succeeds before bundling.
```

next i tried:

```
Marcs-MacBook-Pro:smartforce marcboehle$ sudo gem install pg
Password:
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing pg:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for pg_config... yes
Using config values from /usr/bin/pg_config
checking for libpq-fe.h... yes
checking for libpq/libpq-fs.h... yes
checking for pg_config_manual.h... yes
checking for PQconnectdb() in -lpq... yes
checking for PQconnectionUsedPassword()... yes
checking for PQisthreadsafe()... yes
checking for PQprepare()... yes
checking for PQexecParams()... yes
checking for PQescapeString()... yes
checking for PQescapeStringConn()... yes
checking for PQescapeLiteral()... yes
checking for PQescapeIdentifier()... yes
checking for PQgetCancel()... yes
checking for lo_create()... yes
checking for pg_encoding_to_char()... yes
checking for pg_char_to_encoding()... yes
checking for PQsetClientEncoding()... yes
checking for PQlibVersion()... yes
checking for PQping()... yes
checking for PQsetSingleRowMode()... no
checking for rb_encdb_alias()... yes
checking for rb_enc_alias()... yes
checking for rb_thread_call_without_gvl()... yes
checking for rb_thread_call_with_gvl()... yes
checking for rb_thread_fd_select()... yes
checking for rb_w32_wrap_io_handle()... no
checking for PGRES_COPY_BOTH in libpq-fe.h... no
checking for PGRES_SINGLE_TUPLE in libpq-fe.h... no
checking for PG_DIAG_TABLE_NAME in libpq-fe.h... no
checking for struct pgNotify.extra in libpq-fe.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for ruby/st.h... yes
creating extconf.h
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR="
compiling gvl_wrappers.c
compiling pg.c
pg.c:272:9: warning: implicit declaration of function 'PQlibVersion' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
        return INT2NUM(PQlibVersion());
               ^
In file included from pg.c:48:
In file included from ./pg.h:17:
In file included from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby.h:33:
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/ruby.h:1167:21: note: instantiated from:
# define INT2NUM(v) INT2FIX((int)(v))
                    ^
pg.c:272:9: note: instantiated from:
        return INT2NUM(PQlibVersion());
               ^
pg.c:272:17: note: instantiated from:
        return INT2NUM(PQlibVersion());
                       ^
pg.c:375:48: error: use of undeclared identifier 'PQPING_OK'
        rb_define_const(rb_mPGconstants, "PQPING_OK", INT2FIX(PQPING_OK));
                                                      ^
pg.c:375:56: note: instantiated from:
        rb_define_const(rb_mPGconstants, "PQPING_OK", INT2FIX(PQPING_OK));
                                                              ^
pg.c:377:52: error: use of undeclared identifier 'PQPING_REJECT'
        rb_define_const(rb_mPGconstants, "PQPING_REJECT", INT2FIX(PQPING_REJECT));
                                                          ^
pg.c:377:60: note: instantiated from:
        rb_define_const(rb_mPGconstants, "PQPING_REJECT", INT2FIX(PQPING_REJECT));
                                                                  ^
pg.c:379:57: error: use of undeclared identifier 'PQPING_NO_RESPONSE'
        rb_define_const(rb_mPGconstants, "PQPING_NO_RESPONSE", INT2FIX(PQPING_NO_RESPONSE));
                                                               ^
pg.c:379:65: note: instantiated from:
        rb_define_const(rb_mPGconstants, "PQPING_NO_RESPONSE", INT2FIX(PQPING_NO_RESPONSE));
                                                                       ^
pg.c:381:56: error: use of undeclared identifier 'PQPING_NO_ATTEMPT'
        rb_define_const(rb_mPGconstants, "PQPING_NO_ATTEMPT", INT2FIX(PQPING_NO_ATTEMPT));
                                                              ^
pg.c:381:64: note: instantiated from:
        rb_define_const(rb_mPGconstants, "PQPING_NO_ATTEMPT", INT2FIX(PQPING_NO_ATTEMPT));
                                                                      ^
1 warning and 4 errors generated.
make: *** [pg.o] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/pg-0.16.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/pg-0.16.0/ext/gem_make.out
```

and then i gave the following a try:

```
Marcs-MacBook-Pro:smartforce marcboehle$ which pg_config
/usr/bin/pg_config
Marcs-MacBook-Pro:smartforce marcboehle$ gem install pg -- --with-pg-config= '/usr/bin/pg_config'
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
    Permission denied - /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/pg-0.16.0/.gemtest
Marcs-MacBook-Pro:smartforce marcboehle$ sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
Password:
sudo: apt-get: command not found
Marcs-MacBook-Pro:smartforce marcboehle$ sudo install libpq-dev
usage: install [-bCcpSsv] [-B suffix] [-f flags] [-g group] [-m mode]
               [-o owner] file1 file2
       install [-bCcpSsv] [-B suffix] [-f flags] [-g group] [-m mode]
               [-o owner] file1 ... fileN directory
       install -d [-v] [-g group] [-m mode] [-o owner] directory ...
Marcs-MacBook-Pro:smartforce marcboehle$ sudo apt-get install postgresql-client libpq5 libpq-dev
sudo: apt-get: command not found
Marcs-MacBook-Pro:smartforce marcboehle$ sudo gem install pg
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'pg' (>= 0), here is why:
          Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server session ticket A (https://rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)
ERROR:  Possible alternatives: pg
Marcs-MacBook-Pro:smartforce marcboehle$ rails -v
Could not find pg-0.16.0 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
Marcs-MacBook-Pro:smartforce marcboehle$ ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [x86_64-darwin12.3.0]
Marcs-MacBook-Pro:smartforce marcboehle$ rails -v
Could not find pg-0.16.0 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

EDIT

Thanks for your comments, i tried to install postgres which led to the following problems. any suggestions or can you recommend a tutorial how i can delete everything connected to the whole ruby on rails, rvm, homebrew and whatever i installed.
Then i would love to reinstall everything clean from the beginning.
otherwise can you help me out with a explanation what i need to do with the "Path" i need to do anything with. i'm a total rooky.

```
An error occurred while installing pg (0.16.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install pg -v '0.16.0'` succeeds before bundling.
Marcs-MacBook-Pro:smartforce marcboehle$ brew update
Updated Homebrew from 424c84c5 to 9e01e61d.
==> New Formulae
clojurescript       libgsm      snzip           voltdb
dmalloc         libresample     stlviewer
dtrx            randomize-lines tlassemble
juju            reaver      tractorgen
==> Updated Formulae
abcl                    isl
ace                 iso-codes
aircrack-ng             ispc
appledoc                ispell
aspell                  jenkins
autoconf                jsvc
automake                klavaro
bash                    kytea
boost                   lcdf-typetools
botan                   ldid
bullet                  leiningen
calc                    lesstif
camlp5                  libcouchbase
cantera                 libdiscid
casperjs                libdlna
chruby                  libfreenect
classads                libmagic
cpanminus               libquvi
cppcheck                llvm
css-crush               logentries
csync                   lpc21isp
cyassl                  mackup
denominator             macvim
djvulibre               madplay
drush                   mariadb
dub                 matlab2tikz
duti                    mksh
eet                 mlton
eina                    mongodb
ejabberd                monotone
elixir                  mr
embryo                  mspdebug
eprover                 mysql
exiftool                mysql-cluster
fb-client               mysql-connector-odbc
fdk-aac                 nasm
findbugs                netcdf
flac                    netpbm
fontforge               nexus
fox                 node
fwknop                  open-scene-graph
gdal                    openssl
gearman                 parrot
geos                    passenger
getmail                 pcre++
gettext                 percona-server
gfortran                perl-build
git                 pgbadger
gle                 pgtap
glm                 pngquant
gnupg2                  poppler
go                  postgis
gobject-introspection           postgresql
gpg-agent               proguard
grass                   py2cairo
gst-libav               pypy
gst-plugins-bad             python
gst-plugins-base            python3
gst-plugins-good            qemu
gst-plugins-ugly            quantlib
gstreamer               rabbitmq
hevea                   rabbitmq-c
hiredis                 reattach-to-user-namespace
hydra                   redis
icu4c                   rethinkdb
ircd-hybrid             riak
rpm                 tiger-vnc
rrdtool                 transmission
rtmpdump                uwsgi
ruby                    vifm
saxon                   vimpc
sbcl                    voldemort
sdl2                    watchman
ser2net                 wine
serf                    wkhtmltopdf
silk                    wxmac
smartmontools               xmlto
socat                   xpa
sonar                   xrootd
sonar-runner                yarp
sqsh                    yaws
ssdeep                  ydict
storm                   youtube-dl
subversion              zabbix
svtplay-dl              zookeeper
swi-prolog              zsh-completions
tbb                 zsh-syntax-highlighting
terminal-notifier
==> Deleted Formulae
clojure
Marcs-MacBook-Pro:smartforce marcboehle$ brew doctor
Warning: Some directories in /usr/local/share/man aren't writable.
This can happen if you "sudo make install" software that isn't managed
by Homebrew. If a brew tries to add locale information to one of these
directories, then the install will fail during the link step.
You should probably `chown` them:

    /usr/local/share/man/man7

Warning: "config" scripts exist outside your system or Homebrew directories.
`./configure` scripts often look for *-config scripts to determine if
software packages are installed, and what additional flags to use when
compiling and linking.

Having additional scripts in your path can confuse software installed via
Homebrew if the config script overrides a system or Homebrew provided
script of the same name. We found the following "config" scripts:

    /opt/sm/pkg/active/bin/curl-config
    /opt/sm/pkg/active/bin/ncurses5-config
    /opt/sm/pkg/active/bin/ncursesw5-config
    /opt/sm/pkg/active/bin/pkg-config
    /opt/sm/pkg/active/bin/xml2-config
    /opt/sm/pkg/active/bin/xslt-config

Warning: An outdated version of Git was detected in your PATH.
Git 1.7.10 or newer is required to perform checkouts over HTTPS from GitHub.
Please upgrade: brew upgrade git

Warning: You have MacPorts or Fink installed:
  /opt/local/bin/port

This can cause trouble. You don't have to uninstall them, but you may want to
temporarily move them out of the way, e.g.

  sudo mv /opt/local ~/macports

Warning: Your compilers are different from the standard versions for your Xcode.
If you have Xcode 4.3 or newer, you should install the Command Line Tools for
Xcode from within Xcode's Download preferences.
Otherwise, you should reinstall Xcode.

Warning: /usr/bin occurs before /usr/local/bin
This means that system-provided programs will be used instead of those
provided by Homebrew. The following tools exist at both paths:

    git
    git-cvsserver
    git-receive-pack
    git-shell
    git-upload-archive
    git-upload-pack

Consider amending your PATH so that /usr/local/bin
occurs before /usr/bin in your PATH.
Marcs-MacBook-Pro:smartforce marcboehle$ brew upgrade git
Warning: It appears you have MacPorts or Fink installed.
Software installed with other package managers causes known problems for
Homebrew. If a formula fails to build, uninstall MacPorts/Fink and try again.
Error: git not installed
Marcs-MacBook-Pro:smartforce marcboehle$ sudo mv /opt/local ~/macports
Marcs-MacBook-Pro:smartforce marcboehle$ brew upgrade git
Error: git not installed
Marcs-MacBook-Pro:smartforce marcboehle$ brew install git
==> Downloading http://git-core.googlecode.com/files/git-1.8.3.4.tar.gz
######################################################################## 100,0%
==> make prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/git/1.8.3.4 sysconfdir=/usr/local/etc CC=cc CF
==> make CC=cc CFLAGS= LDFLAGS=
git-credential-osxkeychain.c:131: error: ‘protocol’ undeclared (first use in this function)
git-credential-osxkeychain.c:131: error: ‘kSecProtocolTypeHTTPS’ undeclared (first use in this function)
git-credential-osxkeychain.c:133: error: ‘kSecProtocolTypeHTTP’ undeclared (first use in this function)
git-credential-osxkeychain.c:141: error: ‘port’ undeclared (first use in this function)
make: *** [git-credential-osxkeychain.o] Error 1

READ THIS: https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/troubleshooting

These open issues may also help:
    https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/21998
    https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/21530
    https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/pull/17713
    https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/pull/20260
Marcs-MacBook-Pro:smartforce marcboehle$ brew upgrade git
Error: git not installed
Marcs-MacBook-Pro:smartforce marcboehle$
```

Comment: How did you install postgres to start? I'd highly recommend using [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/). It's as simple as brew install postgres.

Comment: Also, apt-get is a Debian/Ubuntu/etc. command -- you won't be able to use it on OSX. Homebrew functions very similarly though.

Comment: actually i dont know what postgres is. i installed ruby with rvm (after trying a lot as an absolute beginner) and after that i started with one month railes. to work with image magick i needed to install homebrew. i will read a bit about postgres and trying to install it via homebrew. thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, a recommendation to try using `sqlite3` as your database provider if you're new...  It's just a single file, MUCH simpler to deal with compared to postgres.

It sounds like you don't have postgres or it's out of date.  Installing applications on the system itself is not recommended, instead you can install them for your use using [Homebrew](http://brew.sh).  It looks like you tried a debian/ubuntu apt-get command, it's similar to those management systems, but for OS X.

Make sure you have XCode installed, and install the command line tools using it (there's a button in XCode's preferences to do so easily).

Comment: I don't agree with the `sqlite3` part. The setup might be simpler but you're still going to run into these bumps when switching out, the simplicity is abstracted by Rails anyway.

Comment: Deal with problems as needed and no sooner...  If (likely never) a postgres migration is needed for their billion dollar app, they'll have the resources to easily tackle it.

Comment: i tried to install postgres which led to the problem above. any suggestions? @NickVeys

Comment: I recommend not using postgres, if you just want to use Rails and get started you absolutely don't need it.  If you really want to, use Homebrew and install it, as above.

Comment: As i mentioned, i have no idea what postgres is and why i would need it. i just wanted to follow my tutorial but whenever i try to start a rails server or do anything else it says i cant install pg gem and i already tried several different ways of installing pg gem without any luck

Comment: Ok, in that case, in your Gemfile, find `gem 'pg'` and replace it with `gem 'sqlite3'`.  Run `bundle`, and try starting.  Postgres is a database server, but sqlite3 is a simple, file-based database that needs far less setup.

Comment: this might have helped. my gemfile contained both, sqlit3 and pg file. after taking pg file out it might work. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Try installing the packet `libpq-dev`